# Undefined offset after Json deserialization

Tags: php, json

I made a code for deserialize a JSON, all working good for some content but for this [link](http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/351/teams) I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\SF\Teams.php on line 12

on this line: `$current_object = $decoded[$i];`

this is my code:

```
$variable = file_get_contents("http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/351/teams");
$decoded = json_decode($variable, true);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($decoded); $i++) {

 $current_object = $decoded[$i];
 var_dump($current_object); ...
```

Comment: Instead of usinf `for` loop use `foreach` instead

Comment: In my for I use this arguments: for ($i = 0; $i < count($decoded); $i++); in the foreach loop how transform this?

Comment: `foreach($decoded as $key => $value){ print_r($value);}`

Comment: @HaroldFinch please check out my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code the output the `team name` and `Short name`

Try Example

```
$variable = file_get_contents("http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/351/teams");
$decoded = json_decode($variable, true);

foreach($decoded['teams'] as $team)
{
    echo "Team name: ".$team['name']."<br />";
    echo "Short name: ".$team['shortName']."<br />";
    echo "<hr>";
}
```